# How to merge C# webpages in vb.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an existing vb.net web application, I want to add some C#.net web pages in that application. I don't want to create subsite for that pages.

Comment: Is it possible to shorten this question somehow?

Comment: I doubt you can do it, as you cannot mix VB.Net and C# in the same DLL, which is what you are essentially trying to do here (the web pages code behind files are compiled into the site DLL).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and we are also managing some projects which has 2 languages(VB,C#) for web application.

What i suggest is to copy the vb web page to the project folder and include them to project.(include .vb,.designer.vb) 
now just build the application and set the start up page as the newly added vb web page.

I hope it should work.
cheers.:)